# Checking if array contains char

Tags: c++, arrays, char, contains

Ok, this is what I have been trying to do, please correct me if I am wrong I am trying to check if myarray contains the char abcd. What I am thinking of doing it this way:

```
char* myarray[] = {
    "hello",
    "wooorld",
    "hi"};

if(myarray->Contains(abcd))
{
//do stuff
}
```

My question is, is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: When there isn't any specific ordering to your array/list/vector/container, you *have* to search through the entire thing if you are checking for the existence of an element.

Comment: You can use `std::find`.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/

Answer (score 6):

One way do it is to use `std::string` and `std::vector` with `std::find` algorithm:

```
 std::vector<std::string> strs{"hello","wooorld","hi"};
 std::string toFind = "abcd";
 if (std::find(strs.begin(), strs.end(), toFind) != strs.end())
 {
    std::cout <<" abcd exist in vector of strings";
 }
```

Comment: std::vector<std::string> strs{"hello","wooorld","hi"};        

this line ie expecting a ;   for some reason ( I included <vector> and <string>, not sure what would be the cause )

Comment: @bLu3eYeZ `{}` is uniform initialization since C++11, make sure you enabled C++11 when you compile the code or you can C++03 style initialization.

Answer (score 0):

If you sort the array of **C-style strings**, there are other *"better"* ways of finding text.

To name a few:
Binary search
Fibonacci search

You need to clarify the term *"better"*.  For small containers, a linear search performs better than a binary search.